# Remove components from a feature using Drush

Tags: drush, features

Using Features UI to manage a big feature components is a tedious task.

Therefore in order to **add a new component** I use

```
drush fe myfeature views_view:myview1
```

Now how I **remove the uneeded component** myview2?

From the UI this operation is illustrated as below, I want to remove the conflicted community_content with clone_of_community_content:

The view:

[image]

Comment: If you think my answer was correct, please mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 8):

Remove the component by deleting the corresponding line in your feature's .info file. Then run:

`$ drush fu <feature_name>`

In your case:

1. Open the file `/sites/all/<features_folder>/myfeature/myfeature.info`.
2. Delete the following line.

   `features[views_view][] = myview2`
3. Save the file.
4. Run `$ drush fu myfeature` in your site's folder.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work for rules. I deleted a `features[rules_config]` and it didn't delete the `.rules_defaults.inc` file.

Comment: You may manually need to remove these files also.

Comment: I tried this for variable/strongarm. I removed every trace of the variables. But on `drush cc all; drush fu -y FEATURENAME` all the stuff was re-added.

Answer (score 2):

There's **no direct drush command** (Drupal 7.31 & Drush version 6.3.0 and never heard such a thing for drush verson 7.x) to disable/remove an component. If you only want to remove the component, then you should do it with features UI.

But if you want to delete a field (for example), there how I do with drush :

1. First be sure that your field is not use in a custom module.
   (If necessary you will have to adjust your code)
2. Then let's ask drush to delete the field : `drush field-delete field_website`
3. Small check if field was really delete : `drush field-info fields | grep field_website`
4. And just recreate the features where you field was included : `drush fu myfeature`
5. If you are using git you can also check that your change make sense (I assume that you know how to use `cd` or relativ/absolut path) : `git diff myfeature`

Hope that help.